# XAMPP / MySQL File Import

Tags: mysql, xampp

Is it possible to import a large file directly into MySQL ?
The file size is approximately 30MB and contains approximately 30k records.
The file that I am attempting to import is a SQL insert query

Comment: 30MB is not large. I'd even go so far as to call that trivial. What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: When using  SOURCE followed by the file path and file name an error returns informing me that MySQL has gone away

Comment: Please show the command you're using, and also check your MySQL logs for any indication of a problem.

Comment: The command I’m using is SOURCE file path\file name

Comment: Usually this is done with `LOAD DATA INFILE` for more control. You may have a SQL syntax error somewhere in there. Have you tried applying chunks of this file to narrow down the problem? Do you know how far it gets before crashing out?

Comment: I have reduced this to 1/3 of the file size and it still becomes disconnected from the server when trying to use SOURCE

Comment: It is very frustrating as to why this is so difficult to achieve

Comment: You may want to try with something really simple that absolutely must work and build up from there. Like `SELECT 1;` or something. I really don't use `SOURCE`, instead things like `mysql ... < source.sql` instead using pipes.

Comment: I have also tried executing this from cmd changing the file path and relocating the file into the bin folder, but it still crashes. Is there something in the configuration file that needs to be modified maybe?

Comment: If it's crashing you must check the server logs. It's probably trying to tell you something but you're not listening.

Comment: Ultimately what I am trying to do is move away from using MS Excel for handling large datasets

Comment: Sure, but check your server logs. Something's wrong with your server if it keeps imploding like that. If possible check you're using the latest version of it. If necessary, reinstall.